Реакция антивируса браузера на скомпилированные приложения на Rust
Когда перекидывал другу скомпилированное приложение Tauri обнаружил, что антивирус браузера считает файл подозрительным. Сначала подумал на Tauri, но тоже самое происходит с приложением на Slint и Macroquad.
Как мне компилировать код на Rust таким образом, чтобы защита браузера и защита Windows не жаловалась на него?



Любой неподписанный exe-файл будет подозрительным, и Rust тут ни при чём. А подписать его вы не сможете, потому что санкции

Подписать файл можно (почти) без проблем несмотря на санкции. А вот неподозрительным подписанный файл автоматически не становится.
